# What is the equivalent of Query.count in the SQLAlchemy 1.4 ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a SQLAlchemy ORM model like this

```py
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String())
```

In SQLAlchemy 1.4 / 2.0, the ORM's `session.query` idiom is being unified with the SQLAlchemy core `select` function*, so to fetch all `Foo`s we would do

```
foos = session.execute(Foo).scalars().all()
```

instead of

```
foos = session.query(Foo).all()
```

In the current (sqlalchemy<=1.3) ORM we can obtain the number of `Foo`s in the database with this query:

```
nfoos = session.query(Foo).count()
```

But how can we get the count in SQLALchemy 1.4?

```
session.execute(sa.select(Foo).count())
```

raises

> AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'count'

```
session.execute(sa.select(Foo)).count()
```

raises

> AttributeError: 'ChunkedIteratorResult' object has no attribute 'count'

```
session.execute(sa.select(sa.func.count(Foo)))
```

raises

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression element expected, got `<class '__main__.Foo'>`.

This works,

```
session.execute(sa.select(sa.func.count(Foo.id))).scalars()
```

but specifying an attribute seems less OO / elegant than the `Query.count` version.  Moreover, it precludes building a query but deferring the decision of whether to retrieve the count or the model instances.

What is the idiomatic way to get the `count()` of an ORM query in the new SQLAlchemy 1.4 world?

---

* the `session.query()` API will still work in 1.4 and later

Comment: @YaakovBressler yes, but I'm specifically asking about the new API defined in 1.4.

Comment: Don't see a `count()` method on `Result`. Perhaps `select(func.count()).select_from(Foo)`, if you don't like counting the pk?

Comment: It's used in an example in the new docs here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data.html#explicit-from-clauses-and-joins

Comment: @IljaEverilä I've edited to clarify my objection to counting the pk.  Essentially, with `session.query` I can build a query (perhaps dynamically) and decide later whether to call `count` or `all` etc.  Now it seems I need to decide in advance whether I am counting or fetching?  That said, `select_from` works, but seems a little obscure,

Comment: Hmm, somewhat the same can be achieved by passing the former query as a subquery to `select_from()`. `Query.count()` does the same, i.e. it wraps the query in a subquery and emits `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) anon`.

Comment: Aye, though as an anecdote I never during the time I actively used SQLA actually had a use for it (`Query.count()`), precisely because of the wrapping, which can end up in not so great query plans. But I do think it is/was nice as an ad-hoc tool, when interactively trying out things.

Comment: @IljaEverilä If no-one else chips in I may write an answer tomorrow, based on your comments, unless you want to write an answer yourself?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4)'s comments, it seems that there is no direct equivalent to [Query.count](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count) in the [new ORM-querying API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_objects.html) released in SQLAlchemy 1.4 (in beta at the time of writing).

The functional equivalent is to call `count()`, selecting from a subquery*

```py
from sqlalchemy import func, select

count = (
    session.execute(select(func.count()).select_from(select(Foo).subquery()))
    .scalar_one()
)
```

Generating this SQL

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
 FROM (SELECT foo.id AS id, foo.name AS name 
         FROM foo) 
AS anon_1
```

Counting an attribute, such as the primary key column, generates a simple `SELECT COUNT`

```py
count = session.execute(select(func.count(Foo.id))).scalar_one()
```

```sql
SELECT count(foo.id) AS count_1 
FROM foo
```

`Query.count` is still supported in 1.4, so it can still be used, as can all the ORM features available in 1.3.

---

* `Query.count` [also selects from a subquery](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#counting) rather than executing `SELECT COUNT` directly.

Comment: Very darn complicated for such a basic operation! `db.session.execute(
    sa.select(sa.func.count(some_previous_stmt.froms[0].c.id))
).scalar()`

Comment: The scalars().one() can be simplified using `scalar_one()` as you know the count result will only have a single row with a single column.

Answer (score 4):

If you have constructed a complex `query` with joins and several conditions, you can count the query results like this:

```
count_query = query.with_only_columns(func.count(Foo.id))
count = session.execute(count_query).scalar_one()
```

The idea is to use a copy of the query and replace the selected columns with a single count column.

Comment: Works. Noted that if your query has an `order_by` it might complain with `column "x.y" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or aggregation`

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with Flask, SQLAlchemy's `session` is equivalent to `db.session` in Flask-SQLAlchemy (correct me if I'm wrong), here are examples for simple counts:

**Legacy:**

```
>>> db.session.query(Order).count()
2111
```

**2.0 syntax (simple row count in table):**

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import func
>>> db.session.scalar(db.select(func.count(Order.order_id)))
2111
```

I would assume counting on any column is safe, and count does not eliminate duplicates (I assure, I don't have 2000+ currencies):

```
>>> db.session.scalar(db.select(func.count(Order.currency)))
2111
```

P.S. generated SQL by select statement `print(db.select(func.count(Order.currency)))` :

```
SELECT count("order".currency) AS count_1 
FROM "order"
```

**2.0 syntax (using subqueries):**

Counting from subquery is more elaborate as others have suggested.

```
>>> to_filter = db.select(Order).where(Order.currency=='GBP')
>>> db.session.scalar(db.select(func.count()).select_from(to_filter))
17
```

Answer (score 2):

For me - using Flask-Sqlalchemy, with the SQLAlchemy Version 2.X - this worked:

```
subselect = db.select(Tablename).filter_by(user_id=current_user.id, ...)

select = db.select(db.func.count()).select_from(subselect)

number_of_rows = db.session.execute(select).scalar_one()
```

Shoutout to @snakecharmerb - on strike

for giving the answer to his/her own question and really helping me out there!

Comment: I don't understand this. Should
`number_of_rows = db.session.execute(query).scalar_one()`
read as
`number_of_rows = db.session.execute(select).scalar_one()`?

Comment: You are super right @boom100100 I've edited my amswer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use rowcount

```
# using sqlalchemy

  from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    def connect_to_db():
        """Create database connection."""
        url = f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{db_pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}"
        try:
            engine = create_engine(url)
            return engine.connect()
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
    
    
    def execute_query(query):
        connection = connect_to_db()
        with connection as con:
            result = con.execute(query)
            return result

    results = execute_query("show tables;")
    print("count = ",results.rowcount)

    output: count =  1298
```

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=rowcount#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.rowcount) suggest that this is not a reliable approach.